# How to exclude ID from click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I`m new to jQuery and would like to know how I can edit a click function.

Here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<ul class="result">
   <li id="a"></li>
   <li></li> //will be added through a loop depending on input
</ul>
```

So my problem is that when I will click at the `li` object it will do something.  Now I would like to exclude `li id="a"` from that event. I thought `return false;` would handle this but it does not.

Here is what the jQuery function looks like:

```
$('.result li').click(function() { 
    $('.result li a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
        some further code...
});
```

I also tried:

```
$('.result li').click(function() { 
    $('.result li a').click(function () {
        return false;
    });
        some further code...
});
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: What does "hit" refer to?

Comment: sorry that was just a typo, its `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
$('.result li').click(function() {     
       if($(this).attr('id')!="your id")
        some further code...
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('.result li:not(#a)').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.result li').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        some further code...
    }
});
```

Here, `this` means the element in the current scope, which is always the `li` clicked here.

and `e.target` means the element actually clicked, which can be `li` or `a`.

So, in case the element actually clicked is not the `li` in the current scope, `e.target === this` return false and nothing happens (no click event is fired) and vice-versa.

Comment: Or, use my answer, and the click event isn't attached whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

A simple if should work:

```
$('.result li').click(function(ev) { 
  if (this.id == "a") {
    return; 
  }

  // Do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A negation pseudo-class(:not(X)) will do the job. You can get a better idea on negation pseudo-class [Here](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/)

Now please try with this one

```
$('.result li:not(#a)').click(function() {

    // Your code here...

}
```